# How to login to a Linux server without SSH key?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I had setup a SSH key to login into my linux server but the SSH public and private key have now been deleted from my personal computer. How can I login into my Linux server with the username and password ?

Currently when I try to login in , I'm getting the following error :

```
username@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You will need alternative root access to the server so you can modify /etc/ssh/ssh_config and restart - at which point its likely easier (and more secure) to just replace your public key on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to restore your private key from your latest backup prior to the mishap that caused it to be deleted or otherwise irretrievable.

An alternative way would be to gain console/kvm access to the Linux server, manually log in using your user credentials, and add the public key of your new ssh keypair to your authorized_keys file - naturally after configuring, performing, and testing your backup.

Comment: It would also be useful to investigate how the pubic key was deleted from the server. The private key probably should never have been there but only on the user's desktop.

Comment: @doneal24 the OP never stated that the public key was deleted from the server, nor that the private key was on there.

Comment: @davidgo I misread the question. I now agree with the answer to restore the keys from the user's backups and to be more careful about deleting files from your desktop.